# References for MVC extension methods differ between vbhtml and cshtml files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am converting the login views of an application from `vbhtml` to `cshtml`.  In the vbhtml files the original developer calls an `Html.LabelWithAttributesFor` extension method.  When I write the same line of code in the new `cshtml` file the extension method isn't available via Intellisense and fails to compile.  Are references not shared between `vbhtml` and `cshtml` files in a project?

Comment: Are your views in different locations? Check `web.config` in your views directory to ensure that the `<namespaces>` of your extensions are included.

Comment: @BenFoster - The views are in the same folder.  The web.config (in the Views folder) includes the namespace references for the extensions.  The extensions themselves are defined in another project within the solution, but that is correctly referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to circle back and close this question with the "answer".  In the end, what seems to have knocked something loose was when we removed the vbhtml pages from the solution.  All use of the Extensions had been removed prior to our removing the vbhtml pages and other developers had worked on the solution in the interim making other changes.  Fast forward a few months to another developer needing the extensions.  He added a reference to the project with the extension methods and used them on a new cshtml page, which worked fine.  So, the problem is solved but I still have no idea what caused the problem in the first place and I have been unable to reproduce it.